# Can we generalize the regular value theorem even beyond the Ehresmann's theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, fiber-bundles

The formulation is complicated, but the answer may be some clever usage of the partition of unity, because locally the answer is given by the regular value theorem and the whole problem is to glue it to a global thing. Anyway, I don't know how to do it.

**Introduction**

Ehresmann's theorem generalizes the regular value theorem. It states that there is a natural diffeomorphism $$f^{-1}(B_n) \simeq B_n \times f^{-1}(n),$$
where $n$ is a regular value of $f$, $B_n$ is its sufficiently small neighbourhood and $f$ is a smooth proper map between manifolds $f\colon M\to N$ (proper = pre-image of a compact set is compact). We can restrict to the case where $M$ is compact - then $f$ is always proper.

We can easily further generalize it to the case where we take the pre-image of (a neighbourhood of) a smooth submanifold $V$ of $N$ instead of a single point $n\in N$, assuming that the normal bundle to it is trivial: by tubular neighbourhood theorem we can find a neighbourhood of $V$ diffeomorphic to $V\times B$ (where $B$ is a ball in the normal bundle), and deduce the claim by applying the theorem to the composition $\pi_{_B} \circ f$, where $\pi_{_B}$ is the projection $V\times B\to B$.
I want to ask if this diffeomorphism may be natural in some way and if the theorem can be generalized to nontrivial bundles.

**Question**

To formulate the question properly, let's look at normal bundles $\def\N{\mathcal N} \N$. We can see that $$\pi_{\N(V)}\circ f_*:\N(f^{-1}(V))\to \N(V)$$ establishes a fiberwise isomorphism of the bundles (where $\pi_{\N(V)}$ is the orthogonal projection $TN\to \N(V)$) and thus we can think of $\N(f^{-1}(V))$ as a *pullback* of $\N(V)$. Since by the tubular nbhd thm normal bundles are diffeomorphic with the respective neighbourhoods, $f^{-1}(U)$ is some kind of pullback, but we have to go through the normal bundles and tangent maps to see this. The question is if we can represent it as a pullback *naturally with respect to $f$* (not $f_*$). Formally:

> Can we find such diffeomorphisms $\N(f^{-1}(V))\overset{d_M}\to f^{-1}(U)$  and $\N(V)\overset{d_N}\to U$ that the composition:
>   $c = d_N^{-1} \circ f \circ d_M$ is "fiberwise"; i.e., it is a  diffeomorphism on the fibres: $\N_{w}(f^{-1}(V)) \to \N_{f(w)}(V)$ for each $w\in f^{-1}(V)$ (not necessarily equal to $\pi_{\N(V)}\circ f_*$).

**Update:** I think that the orthogonal projection $\pi_{\N(V)}$ in the formula above establishing the pullback may be omitted if we choose appropriate scalar product on $TM$ (divide $T_{f^{-1}(V)}M$ into orthogonal [with respect to any scalar product] subspaces: $\mathrm{ker} f_* \oplus W$ and observe that $W$ is isomorphic to $T_{V}N$ by $f_*$ so it is enough to pull the scalar product back from $TN$ to $V$). Does it help anyhow?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question.  You ask for a generalization but you don't state specifically what you consider the original theorem to be.  Could you state what generality you know Ehresmann's theorem at, and what direction (if any) you would like to generalize it in?  Is there a specific reason you're looking for such a theorem?

Comment: @RyanBudney I describe what I mean by Ehresmann's thm in the first paragraph of the introduction. The second paragraph of the introduction is a bit informal, but sketches the direction I want to go. Normal bundle to the inverse image of a submanifold $V$ [assuming that $f$ is locally submersive <probably transverse to $V$ is also enough>] is a pullback via $f_*$ of the normal bundle to $V$. I ask if there are such diffeomorphisms between the normal bundles and the respective neighbourhoods of $V$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ that the neighbourhood of $f^{-1}(V)$ is a pullback via $f$.

Comment: In the simple case described in the second paragraph of the introduction, I ask for such trivialisations of neighbourhoods of $f^{-1}(V)$ and $V$ as $B\times f^{-1}(V)$ and $B\times V$ respectively that $f$ can be described as a map $f(b,m)=(b,g(m))$. P.S. There is no specific reason for the question, just curiosity and a feeling that it should be true.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are requests for clarification in the comments, I will present my idea of the proof in the simple case, when the normal bundle to $V$ is trivial. The reasoning fails at one point, maybe someone could help.

By the tubular neighbourhood thm an appropriate neighbourhood of $V$ is diffeomorphic to $B\times V$, where $B$ is a ball in the normal bundle. Since $f$ is submersive, locally we can consider it as a projection and we can (locally!) arrange an $f$-related vector fields corresponding to the standard coordinate vector fields in $B$. By compactness we can assume that $B$ is small enough for these constructions. Then, via partition of unity, we can arrange global (in a neighbourhood of the whole $f^{-1}(V)$) vector fields $f$-related to the standard vector fields in $B$.

If these vector fields establish a diffeomorphism between some neighbourhood $f^{-1}(U)$ of $f^{-1}(V)$ and $B\times f^{-1}(V)$, then - in the product coordinates of respective neighbourhoods - $f$ is given by the formula $f(b,m)=(b,f(m))$.

**The thing is that I don't know how to guarantee that these v.f. are "integrable" and how to treat the general case.**

*Edit:* A possible bypass (for integrability) is to fix order of these vector fields and integrate them in that fixed order as in this [proof](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~petersen/manifolds.pdf) (page 29) of Ehresmann's thm by Peter Petersen. By the IFT and compactness it should work. Am I right?